# Change forecolor of disabled combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, colors

I need black forecolor in a disabled combobox. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have searched around for information in the past about this, and as far as I can tell, the best solution is to change the **DrawMode** of the combo box to *OwnerDrawFixed* or *OwnerDrawVariable* and then write your own drawing code in the **DrawItem** event of the combo box.

I found this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/disabledcombodisplay.aspx) that goes into much more detail about it.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

A "hack" I've used in the past for textboxes is to leave the control enabled, but capture the "OnFocus" event and immediately set the focus to some other object on the form, preferably a label since it doesn't show as being selected.  I think this should work for comboboxes, too.

Comment: this could cause some trouble when using the tab key to step through the controls

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if your app is Winforms or WPF. The code given below works in a WPF app.

```
    combo1.Items.Add("Item 1");
    combo1.Items.Add("Item 2");
    combo1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    combo1.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
```

In my XAML I added a combo box and set its IsEnabled property to "false" then in the code behind I used the code given above and it does work.

HTH

Answer (score -2):

All you need to do is say

```
combobox1.ForeColor = Color.FromName("Black");
```

It doesn't matter if the control is disabled or not, it should change the foreground color.

Comment: No this didnt worked: 
tried with : 
            comboBox1.Enabled = false;
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox1.ForeColor = Color.FromName("Red");

Comment: It appears that i was wrong. I created a quick example application that shows this. The best solution that I have found is that you can bold the text to make the gray on gray more readable. The zip of the example application is located here:
http://www.yousendit.com/download/dVlwTXRkUnErV3hMWEE9PQ

Answer (score -3):

comboBox1.BackColor=Color.Black;

Comment: Read the question. It's *forecolor*, not backcolor.